# Error(14,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am having an issue with the trigger below. I am using SQLDeveloperx86 Build 15.21 (v4.0.2.15). The compiler log gives me the error shown in this posts header. Consequently I cant use the trigger as a result. The squiggle line of death appears under the "/" symbol

```
create or replace trigger clientexists
        after insert on DISPATCH
        for each row
        declare 
          countRows Integer;
          begin
            select count(*) into countRows from CLIENT
            where CLIENT.name = DISPATCH.client;
            if countRows = 0 then
                  insert into CLIENT
                  values(:new.client,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            end if;
        end;
        /
        show error
```

Comment: You need to set the delimiter to `/` before creating trigger.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on that, as far as I know I didn't need to set anything in regards to the slash before.

Comment: What does `show error` return?

Comment: You probably have an SQL error in your trigger. Did you checked it?

Comment: Are you compiling this from the SQL Worksheet, in which case it looks fine; or from the code editor window (for an existing trigger, or from choosing table->trigger->create)? The `/` and `show errors` should be omitted from the code editor, and you would get the red squiggle there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're compiling this from the code editor window then the `/` is not valid:

[image: code editor window with error]

And neither is `show errors`, as that would be treated as part of the statement for that trigger, not a separate client command. If you remove both then you'll get an ORA-00904 because you're referring to `DISPATCH.client` instead of `:NEW.client`; with that corrected it compiles:

[image: code editor window working]

But if you execute your code from an SQL Worksheet then you do need the trailing slash and can use `show errors`:

[image: SQL worksheet window]

Comment: Thank you very much for that Alex, it is obvious I am a little confused about this :new command then. I will research this further, do you have any good material on the subject?

Comment: @user4021524 - the documentation on [correlation names](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHEIHAC) is a good place to start.